# Storing data from string Array to String ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have

```
String add_data[] = new String[6];
```

with datas at 0,1,2,3,4,5 indexes.

Also I have

```
 ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

now I need to put the values in all the indexes in add_data at data[0].

How can i do this? please guide me.

Eg. add_data[0]="a";
    add_data[0]="b";

```
data[0] should have "ab"
```

Comment: Even after reading the answers I don't understand the question. Do you have an array and want to fill its elements into an ArrayList? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

use `Arrays.asList(array)` method to copy array to List. In your case - `String[]` to `List<String>`.

Comment: I don't think so it's answer for this question

Comment: @smas Question is little bit unclear bu as I understand it OP wants to copy array to list.

Comment: for me: he wants catenate all add_data elements and put into data (ArrayList) at 0 index

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do, but try this :

```
String temp = "";
for(String s : add_data) {
    temp += s;
}
data.put(temp);
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong for the for loop, you just want for not foreach. Also wouldn't a StringBuilder be better than concatenation in a loop?

Comment: Too much PHP lately ^^ For the Stringbuilder, it's been a while since I saw a benchmark, but I don't remember a performance difference in these kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < add_data.length: i++) {
  result += add_data[i];
}
data.add(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need:

1. Catenate all Strings from your array
2. Put this at 0 index in your ArrayList

Something like this:

```
String addData[] = new String[6];
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();    
addData[0] = "a";
addData[1] = "b";

// 1. catenate all strings
String str = "";
for (String s : addData) {
    str += (s != null)?s:"";
}

// 2. put it into 0 index in your arraylist     
data.add(0, str);
System.out.println(data.get(0));
```